# How to declare a huge constant array

Tags: c, arrays, constants

**Here is my final goal:**

I want to be able to generate every possible image available for a given size in any possible color depth.

In a sense that's not really complicated I mostly have to iterate on each pixel of the array/matrix where the image is represented and iterate again on each possible value for the given pixel.

In real life... That's not really possible to be able to view them all because there is too much possibility even for a monochromatic image, and for the storage, it's the same, even a small size of image generate an impressive amount of file and the hard drive is easily saturated.

So I do that mostly for the fun of doing it, and because I will soon be able to access a cluster and want to try this old project on it. But the old project use the SFML and is not really efficient (also, SFML in a terminal is not really a great idea)

**Now the problem:**

Since I heavily use each different values of a pixel at every iteration, I want to set it on a global constant that will containt every possible value of one. So it's something like an array of 16M array of unsigned char[3]. That give something like 50MB of RAM used just for it, so not something too huge to manage, and most of all, a set of constant values that don't have to be generated on the fly and a nice (I think?) gain of time and efficiency since the data is used constantly.

The problem is that this array is huge, just having it writed take a nice chunk of space (~640MB) and I wonder if the size of this file is a problem, when I try to compile the application while calling it, I get an error with **out of memory allocating xxxx bytes**, is there a better way to get this array setup? Or is the idea just not as good as I imagine it and there is a better way to do what I want?

Generating the content of the array at lauch was my second idea, but it take just so much time that's not interesting, I prefere it spent in the real image generation.

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself: "Do I _really_ need an array that large, or is there a better way?"

Comment: Check `mmap`. It allows to map content of an existing file to memory. You can keep your values in a 64MB file and to map it to memory at program start.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I have every of theses values multiple times during the execution of the application, I don't _need_ to have it and can just pick them when needed from inside one or more loop or something like that, but for efficiency if that can already be in memory that's even better for me

Comment: That sounds like a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Seems like your build machine run out of memory and crashed gcc. Try a different compiler/computer/os? Also you shouldn't define it in the header, declare it in the header and define it in a .c file elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need such an array, especially when it seems you want to keep in `pixel_matrix[i]` the least significant three bytes of `i`.

From the fragment you posted, the values of `pixel_matrix[i]` can be generated as:

```
pixel_matrix[i][0] = (i >> 16) & 0xFF;
pixel_matrix[i][1] = (i >> 8) & 0xFF;
pixel_matrix[i][2] = i & 0xFF;
```

The formulas above renders the storage of `pixel_matrix` useless.

Comment: Implement the formulas in (one or three) macros or inline functions and you can use `pixel_matrix(i, 1)` or `pixel_GREEN(i)`.